# Expand list by repeating values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a size (e.g. 1201) and an arbitrary list (eg. [1,2,3])

I want to make the list 1200 values long, repeating each distinct value roughly equally. So the new list in this case would be [1,1,...,2,2...,3,3] where there are 400 1s, 400 2s, and 401 3s.

Maybe I didn't explain well - it doesn't have to repeat evenly, such as if there's an odd number.

Comment: `np.repeat` is your friend.  Just use `np.repeat(your_list, 400)`

Comment: ok but what if i have an odd number?

Comment: Then be creative.  Maybe make the array one longer than it needs to be and clip it to your desired length.  You could use, for your example, `np.repeat(arr, size//len(arr)+1)[:size]`

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> size = 1201
>>> num_repeats = int(size / len(a))
>>> [val for val in a for _ in range(num_repeats)]
[1, 1, ... 2, 2, ... 3, 3, ...]
```

This will get you as close as you can get using even duplication. From here, you'll need to decide how 'rough' the distribution can be to reach your desired size. If you can't decide, I suppose random insertion would get some sort of result:

```
from random import randrange
result = [val for val in a for _ in range(num_repeats)])
while len(result) < size:
    index = randrange(len(random) + 1)
    result.insert(index, result[index])
```

> Note that `_` is a placeholder for a variable you don't need to use.